# How can I query Google Fit data on Xamarin Forms or Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

How can I query Google Fit data on Xamarin Forms or Xamarin IOS.

My goal is to query the steps taken.

Comment: when I Google "xamarin google fit" the FIRST TWO hits I get are complete sample apps from Xamarin, followed by a bunch of StackOverflow hits.

Comment: Hello, this is correct but it's not for iOS. I have also read the StackOverflow post, there is talk of a Rest Api, but how do you do that.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started

Comment: You don't have a code example for me, do you?

Comment: Have you tried the steps ? It is well explained in the link .

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately without success.

Comment: At which step did you fail ?

Comment: When logging in to IOS with Google

Comment: Is there any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to employ REST for Xamarin. It works on any platforms.
https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/